# How do I embed a YouTube channels latest video on my website that doesn't have a username?

Tags: html, youtube, embed

I know & understand that I can embed a recent YouTube channels video to my website using the following code

```
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=CHANNELUSERNAME" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Unfortunately some of the channels I wish to embed do not have a username, such as "user/CHANNELNAME" they have channel followed by random characters, such as "channel/ABC123defg"

The code above does not work when it is a channel name & not a user name, what code would work in the exact same way for a channel with out a username?

Answer (score 4):

I just realize how to do it. You need to add after embed/ "`+lastest?list=YOUR_CHANNEL_RANDOM_CHARACTERS`".

Example:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/+lastest?list=UUJpTTamTMwx0b7zu12M5Y9Q" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br/>
```

This code allows you to embed a list with the lastest upload video.

Hope it helps.